# Compare static and non-static integer in non-static function

Tags: c++, static, linker, comparison, non-static

I have a static variable that I use as a counter and a non-static version of the variable that I use to save the value of the counter at certain events.  Here is some code:

Header:

```
static int UndoID;
int UndoRedoID;

void SetUnsavedChanges();
```

Class:

At various parts of the class I try something like this:

```
UndoRedoID = UndoID;
```

I've tried other things like:

```
UndoRedoID = myClass:UndoID;
```

Example comparision:

```
void myClass::SetUnsavedChanges()
{
    if (UndoRedoID != UndoID)
    {
        cout << "Unsaved";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Saved";
    }
}
```

This causes me to get linking errors like:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "myClass::UndoID", referenced from:
    myClass::SetUnsavedChanges()       in myClass_lib.a(myClass.o)
    ...
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *define* the static member data, outside the class as:

```
//this should be done in .cpp file
int myClass::UndoID;
```

Let me add one example:

```
//X.h
class X
{
   static int s; //declaration of static member
};
```

then in `X.cpp` file, you should do this:

```
//X.cpp
#include "X.h"

int X::s; //definition of the static member
```

Comment: Some initialization would be also a good idea.