# Strange C++ link error

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, min

When I try to compile this,

```
#include <iostream>

struct K{
    const static int a = 5;
};

int main(){
    K k;

    std::cout << std::min(k.a, 7);
}
```

I get following. Both `gcc` and `clang` gives similar error:

```
/tmp/x-54e820.o: In function `main':
x.cc:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `K::a'
clang-3.7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

if I do following, it compiles without problem. Is this related to the way `std::min` is written?

```
#include <iostream>

struct K{
    const static int a = 5;
};

int main(){
    K k;

    std::cout << std::min((int) k.a, 7);  // <= here is the change!!!
}
```

another way to avoid the error is if I do my own `min()`:

```
template <class T>
T min(T const a, T const b){
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

C-like preprocessor `MIN` also works OK.

Comment: Why are gcc and clang tagged? you should only be using one compiler which by the looks of it is clang

Comment: http://ideone.com/yPtq6w works for me

Comment: Try changing your `min` to take the parameters by reference.

Comment: Your examples should have `#include <algorithm>`  for `std::min`

Comment: Since C++11 another workaround is to use the list-form of min: `std::min({k.a, 7})`  . I think this is not odr-use because initializer lists copy by value. Since C++14 the list form even yields a `constexpr`.

Comment: Also see the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928373/compare-static-and-non-static-integer-in-non-static-function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::min` accepts arguments by reference.  Binding a reference to an object means that the object is *odr-used*  (there is a code sample in [basic.def.odr]/2 pretty much the same as your sample).

However in the `(int)k.a` case, `k.a` is not *odr-used*; because it is performing lvalue-to-rvalue conversion which yields a constant expression.  (There are a few other conditions here too but your code is OK).

If an object is *odr-used* then there must be exactly one definition of it; with no diagnostic required for violating this rule. So the first case may or may not be accepted; and the second case must be accepted.

In your own version of `min`, it takes arguments by value, which is similar to the `(int)k.a` case - the only action taken on `k.a` there is rvalue conversion to initialize the parameter of your `min`.

You can read the full set of rules about *odr-use* in section [[basic.def.odr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr) of a C++ standard draft.

Comment: a line `const int K::a;` is whats missing

Comment: @sp2danny not necessarily; e.g. the second sample is correct without that line

Comment: BTW, 9.4.2 Static data members [class.static.data] §3 is specifically explicit for that use case *If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class
definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignmentexpression
is a constant expression ... **The member shall still be defined
in a namespace scope if it is odr-used** (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not
contain an initializer.*

Answer (score 2):

This question is asked quite often. <strike>I believe it's a bug in clang. `a` is being detected as a constant expression too early and the compiler is not generating a definition of it.</strike> (see correction in comments)

`std::min` takes its arguments by const reference, so a definition must exist.

```
#include <iostream>

struct K{
    const static int a = 5;
};

int main(){
    K k;

    std::cout << std::min(k.a, 7);
}
```

Here's a portable <strike>workaround</strike> alternative:

```
#include <iostream>

struct K{
    constexpr static int a() { return 5; }
};


int main(){
    K k;

    std::cout << std::min(k.a(), 7);
}
```

Comment: IIRC also the optimization level might affect this.

Comment: @juzzlin it fails to link on apple clang with no optimisation. The compiler is failing to figure out the ODR-use of a correctly.

Comment: @Richard Hodges Ok, I just remember I have run into this with GCC on Ubuntu and it worked without optimizations, but failed with -O3 or something like that :p

Comment: No it is not a bug (I thought it was too...). But a static const integral initialisation is still not a definition according to standard : 9.4.2 Static data members [class.static.data] §3 *If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class
definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignmentexpression
is a constant expression ... **The member shall still be defined
in a namespace scope if it is odr-used** (3.2) ... and the namespace scope definition shall not
contain an initializer.*

Comment: @SergeBallesta correction made to post in response. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Your have declared a static variable (a) in your struct, but you have not defined it.

```
struct K
{
    const static int a; // declaration
};

const int K::a = 5; // definition 


int main()
{
    std::cout << std::min(K::a, 7);
}
```

You may find [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) helpful.

I also agree with Richard Hodges answer.

Comment: This would not work for the same reason that OP's attempt would not work.

Comment: You are right. I was using g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall and it worked. Removing -O2 make it doesn't. I'm going to edit the answer.